# Scroll issue with line height & Titillum Web font family

Tags: css, fonts

If I use **Titillium web** font family I can scroll on `<span>` and `<input>` with `line-height` value not `normal` and `<1.6`. But not when I use **San-serif**. I expect when I use `line-height:1.4` there is no scroll.

I don't know, is it because of `inline-block` behavior?

```css
.box {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
input {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Titillium web;
    padding: 0;
}
input.test {
    line-height: 1.2;
}
input.test-2 {
    line-height: normal;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Titillium web;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
      
    background-color: aqua;
}
    
p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Titillium web;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <span>@@@@</span><input type="text" value='@@@@' /><input class="test" type="text" value='@@@@' /><input class="test-2" type="text" value='@@@@' />
</div>
<p>@@@@@@@@@@@@@</p>
```

Here are my question:

1. Is each font family have different optimal `line-height`?
2. If so, when I should use `line-height: normal`? Because many articles suggest using specific `line-height`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same value in line-height and font-size. Instead of `1.4` put `16px` in line-height also.